# Export System.Web.Ui.WebControls.Table in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel-2007, export-to-excel

How to display leading zeroes in excel when we export table in EXCEL using HTML table cell logic?
If the number format is '00001' then in excel automatically converts it to '1'
but I want it as '00001' not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use style in your table

```
protected void Btn_ExportClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
  Response.ClearContent();
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls");
  Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
  gvUsers.RenderControl(htw);

  // Style is added dynamically
  Response.Write(style);
  Response.Write(sw.ToString());
  Response.End();
}

protected void gvUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
      e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("class", "text");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string quote it so that excel treats it as a string rather than a number

Comment: I don't want to see "". I Just want answer as 0001 not "0001"

Answer (score 0):

00001 is not a number, 1 is...  Because no number can start with 0 unless the value itself is 0.
If you want it to display 00001 use qoutes "". So it becomes "00001".
This is also what excel does when you convert a column or cell to General Text.

I think there is no other way to do it.

You can always send microsoft an email with your complaint and ask for an update to fix it :).

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to achieve the same result, just add one line and it will work. Instead of creating style sheet (`.text`) and adding attributes for all  tags using loop, direct apply style on the All `TD` Tags.

Replace

```
string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
```

With

```
string style = @"<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
```

and remove the Loop

Comment: amitvyas100688 - Have you tried the above code? Was this helpful?